# Sql Server sorting query result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

[image]

my purpose is to select chat from tables by RoomId,ChatDate and ChatTime then arrange the result by date and time

what should i add to this query to sort the result by ChatDate and ChatTime ?!

that's what i wrote til now :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_ChatByHour]
    @BeginHour Time(7),
    @EnDHour Time(7), @RoomId int,@ChatDate date
    AS
        BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * 
    FROM Chat 
    WHERE Chat.RoomId=@RoomId 
      and Chat.ChatDate=@ChatDate 
      and  Chat.ChatTime BETWEEN @BeginHour and @EnDHour 
END
```

Comment: @RacerNerd what is the rush? Also if you look at the OP's profile it is clear they know how to accept answers.

Comment: No rush.  I was just trying to make sure it didn't slip without getting marked like so many other questions.

Comment: @RacerNerd doesn't seem to be an issue for this OP.

Comment: Agreed.  With so few points I didn't take the time to look at his profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an order by clause

```
--at the end of the query

order by ChatDate, ChatTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an order by:

```
ORDER BY ChatDate, ChatTime
```

You can see the documentation for it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should add an ORDER BY clause at the end.

```
SELECT ____QUERY______   ORDER BY ChatDate asc, ChatTime asc
```

You can change asc to desc for descending order.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT * FROM Chat WHERE Chat.RoomId=@RoomId and Chat.ChatDate=@ChatDate and   

Chat.ChatTime BETWEEN @BeginHour and @EnDHour

ORDER BY ChatDate, ChatTime
```

and/or DESC depending on what order you need them in